# Getting selected checkbox from database - laravel

Tags: laravel

I am able to save checkbox values into my database. When i am fetching, i try to get the selected checkbox as below but nothing is selected.. What could i be doing wrong in my code please ?

**View**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    @foreach($permission as $value)
                        <li>
                            <label class="fancy-checkbox mb-0">
                                <input type="checkbox" in_array($value->id, $rolePermissions) ? true : false value="{{$value->id}}"  name="permission[]">
                                <span>{{ $value->display_name }}</span>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -
                                <span>{{ $value->description }}</span>

                            </label>
                            <hr>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `.blade` syntax, and you should use `'checked'` instead of `true : false`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $value->id }}" name="permission[]" {{ in_array($value->id, $rolePermissions) ? 'checked' : '' }}/>
```

For checkboxes, simply setting `checked` is all that is required to determine if it should be initially checked or not.

Comment: I just tried with the code above but results is the same..Nothing is selected

Comment: If nothing is checked with that code, then it means that `in_array()` is returning `false`. What specifically does `$rolePermissions` contain? (Add the output of `dd($rolePermissions);` to your question)